# How can I apply these CSS at 2 classes without replicate settings?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have the following problem with a CSS.

In my CSS file I have somethng like this:

```
table.standard-table-cls tbody tr td a {    
    font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#76818a;
}
```

This means that the settings are applied for all the **tbody tr td a** inside a **table** having class **standard-table-cls**

Ok, I neeed that this settings is applied also to all the **tbody tr td a** inside a **table** having class **standard-table-cls-inner-libretto**.

What can I do to apply this settngs also at this table class?

I know that I can replicate the CSS in this way

```
table.standard-table-cls-inner-libretto tbody tr td a { 
    font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#76818a;
}
```

But can I do this thing without replicate it?

Comment: You have to separate rules with comma: `table.standard-table-cls tbody tr td a, table.standard-table-cls-inner-libretto tbody tr td a { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Firstly you 'could' (see below comments) simplify your CSS rule:**

This: `table.standard-table-cls tbody tr td a{...}`

'Could' be changed to: `.standard-table-cls tbody td a{...}`

**2. Secondly, to also apply this to the second ruleset, use a comma:**

`.standard-table-cls tbody td a, .standard-table-cls-inner-libretto tbody td a{...}`

**3. If you wanted to be a bit more swish, although generally not as efficient in terms of rule realisation, you could do, e.g.:**

`[class*=standard-table-cls] tbody td a{...}` which would be applied to both cases

<sup>nb. The above makes a few fairly realistic assumptions about the structure of your HTML/CSS</sup>

Comment: Part 2 is the answer. The simplification in part 1 changes the meaning of the rule, because the original rule does not apply to `a` elements inside `th` elements. It is quite probable that the rule could be simplified in many ways, but we cannot really know, and it’s not relevant to the question asked.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - thus the `nb` at the end. It may `not (be) relevant to the question asked` but I always think that adding a little additional info helps the learning experience, guess I like to think SO can be a little teaching as well as binary Q/A. Regardless, noted above.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
table.standard-table-cls tbody tr td a, table.standard-table-cls-inner-libretto tbody tr td a{    
font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
color:#76818a;
}
```